# How does Keras evaluate loss on test set?

Tags: keras

I am implementing a neural network classifier, to print loss and accuracy  of this NN I'm using:

```
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=False) 
model.metrics_names
print('Test score: ', score[0])    #Loss on test
print('Test accuracy: ', score[1])
```

I would to know how Keras calculate the loss of a model. Specially whether it is evaluated on the first (and only) step of the test set. 
I have search on [keras.io](https://keras.io/models/), but I don't have find anything about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#evaluate):

> **evaluate**
>
> Computes the loss on some input data, batch by batch.
>
> **Returns**
>
> Scalar test loss (if the model has no metrics) or list of scalars (if the model computes other metrics). The attribute `model.metrics_names` will give you the display labels for the scalar outputs.

So it returns you either a single value that represents a loss, or a list of values that correspond to different metrics that were added to your model. These values are calculated based on the whole test set, i. e. all values in `x_test` and `y_test`.

Comment: Is there a way to get loss for each test data besides using a loop and calling evaluate on 1 test data at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, print `model.metrics_names`. Assume the output is `['loss', 'accuracy']`

Then you can do:

```
[test_loss,test_acc] = model.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
print('test accuracy: ',test_acc*100,'%')
print('test loss: ',test_loss)
```